# Flatten (an irregular) list of lists in Python respecting Pandas Dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, yield, flatten

This is a recursive question here on Stackoverflow, yet the solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists-in-python?answertab=active#tab-top) is still not perfect. Yielding is still (for me) one of the most complex things to use in python, so I dont know how to fix it myself.

When an item within any of the lists given to the function is a Pandas dataframe, the flatten function will return its header, instead of the dataframe itself. You can expressly test this by running the following code:

```
import pandas
import collections
df = pandas.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 4), columns=list('ABCD'))

def flatten(l):
    for el in l:
        if isinstance(el, collections.Iterable) and not isinstance(el, basestring):
            for sub in flatten(el):
                yield sub
        else:
            yield el
```

Then, if you call the function given on the referenced post:

```
list(flatten([df]))   #['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
```

Instead of returning a list with the dataframe inside.
How to make the function flatten respect the dataframes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That `flatten` function will recurse down if the element is an instance of `collections.Iterable` and it's not a string (which is iterable, but we usually want to treat it as a scalar, something we're not going to look inside).

Even though `DataFrames` are instances of `collections.Iterable`, it sounds like you want them to be terminal too.  In that case:

```
    if (isinstance(el, collections.Iterable) and 
        not isinstance(el, (basestring, pandas.DataFrame))):
```

After which:

```
>>> list(flatten([[1,2], "2", df]))
[1, 2, '2', <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 100 entries, 0 to 99
Data columns (total 4 columns):
A    100  non-null values
B    100  non-null values
C    100  non-null values
D    100  non-null values
```

Comment: Great, thanks, exactly what I was searching for. I knew how to monkey patch it but this is more elegant that what I was going to do :)